# Sorting overlapping categorical variables in {gtsummary}

Tags: r, dplyr, gtsummary

```
require(gtsummary)

test <- structure(list(`1` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2` = c(1,0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), `3` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0), `4` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `5` = c(1, 0, 1, 1,0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), `6` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `7` = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `8` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0), `9` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10` = c(0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In this example data, I have 10 categorical variables.

```
     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 2     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 4     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
 5     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 6     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 7     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
 8     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 9     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Since they can overlap each other, I have put them in different columns,
using 0 and 1, indicatting "yes" or "no" to having (or not having) the categorical variable.

When `test %>% tbl_summary()`, it creates:
[image]

I would like to sort this by frequency, but

```
test %>% tbl_summary(sort = list(everything() ~ "frequency"))
```

does not work.

Is there anyway to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tbl_summary(sort=)` argument sorts levels within a variable, not the order the variables appear in the table. Variables are appear in the table in the same order they appear in the data frame.

We can update the order in the data frame using the code below.

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

test <- structure(list(`1` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2` = c(1,0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), `3` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0), `4` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `5` = c(1, 0, 1, 1,0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), `6` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `7` = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `8` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0), `9` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10` = c(0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame")) 

# order variables by prevelence 
prev <- purrr::map_dbl(test, mean) %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE)

test %>%
  select(all_of(names(prev))) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable for SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **N = 10** |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 (50%) |
| 2 | 3 (30%) |
| 4 | 3 (30%) |
| 6 | 2 (20%) |
| 1 | 1 (10%) |
| 10 | 1 (10%) |
| 3 | 0 (0%) |
| 7 | 0 (0%) |
| 8 | 0 (0%) |
| 9 | 0 (0%) |

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Daniel, what is it "#> #Uighur"? Oo I haven't it.

Comment: It's a startup message in gtsummary indicating support for #Uighur